# How do I offset the first point on a x limited plot so its not on the y-axis in R?

Tags: r

I'm plotting data points by date using xyplot in R. This was my initial code.

```
xyplot(data$SpainRo ~ data$Date, data= data)
```

I needed to plot the data from a certain point onward so I used this.

```
xyplot(data$SpainRo ~ data$Date, data-data, xlim=as.Date(c("2020-02-27","2020-05-13")))
```

It works however, the first data point for February 27th falls directly on the y-axis, getting obscured. 
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvKV.png)

I was wondering how to move it to the right so the first point isn't on the y-axis.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: expanding your x-axis limits such that it starts a few days earlier? E.g. `xyplot(data$SpainRo ~ data$Date, data-data, xlim=as.Date(c("2020-02-20","2020-05-13")))`

Comment: The only issue with that is that I have data for those days as well (my full date range is January 20th to May 13th). So if I expanded my limit to a few days earlier I would get data points from those days that I don't want to show in my graph.

Comment: In that case I would create a data object filtered by Date such that it only contains the data range which you want to plot. As you set the date cut-off in the filter, you also know how many days ahead of that cut-off you need to set the x-axis minus limit to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the data you don't want to plot, then expand the plot axis.

I'm assuming you are using `xyplot` from the `lattice` package.

```
lattice::xyplot(SpainRo ~ Date, data = data[data$Date > as.Date("2020-02-26"), ], 
                xlim = as.Date(c("2020-02-25","2020-05-13")))
```

Of course, I don't have your `data` because you haven't shared it in your question, so can't demonstrate that this solution works.

Note that you don't need to include `data$` before formula variables if the function takes a `data` argument.